# not getting text color of Firebase UI

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

i am using firebase auth ui for login and designed a theme but not getting text color on the button and Hint option of phone number.
[screenshot of login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWSjB.png)

This is the theme i used...

```
    <style name="LoginTheme" parent="FirebaseUI">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@android:color/white</item>

        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>

        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
```

Coding for the login theme

```
 private void showLoginLayout() {
        AuthMethodPickerLayout authMethodPickerLayout = new AuthMethodPickerLayout
                .Builder(R.layout.layout_sign_in)
                .setPhoneButtonId(R.id.btn_phone_sign_in)
                .setGoogleButtonId(R.id.btn_google_sign_in)
                .build();

        startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
        .setAuthMethodPickerLayout(authMethodPickerLayout)
        .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                .setTheme(R.style.LoginTheme)
        .setAvailableProviders(providers)
        .build(),LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

below code is of that layout file after which i click on register and then the phone number verification opens

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <android.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_phone_sign_in"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sign In with Phone"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_phone_24"/>

        <android.widget.Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_google_sign_in"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sign In with Google"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/fui_ic_googleg_color_24dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what coloraturas is set to `@color/colorAccent`?

Comment: color accent is "black" defined in colors.xml

Comment: post your layout file.

Comment: although i had provided the codes.. But there is no separate layout file for that it goes after clicking that sigin with phone button and then the verification by otp page opens.

Comment: did you found solution to this?